# Google Pie Chart piece background

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, pie-chart

Good day everyone,

is it possible to fill each piece of google piechart with custom image as background?

I didn't find any solution yet. I need it for better infographics presentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating image via svg pattern, appending it to the def and filling with it via fill attribute.
enableInteractivity must be set to false.

```
   window.google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {

        var rectan = $('g g:first-of-type g:nth-of-type(2) rect');
        var patt = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'pattern');

        patt.setAttribute('id', 'img1');
        patt.setAttribute('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse');
        patt.setAttribute('width', '20');
        patt.setAttribute('height', '287');




        var image = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'image');
        image.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', '../Images/bar.png');
        image.setAttribute('x', '0');
        image.setAttribute('y', '0');
        image.setAttribute('width', '20');
        image.setAttribute('height', '287');

        var defs = document.getElementsByTagName('defs')[0];

        patt.appendChild(image);
        defs.appendChild(patt);
        for (var i = 0; i < rectan.length; i++) {
            rectan[i].setAttribute("fill", "url(#img1)");
        }}
```

rectan is a rect element inside the column chart. You just need to change fill attribute for all "pie slices" after first drawing of the chart.

Comment: ty, interesting and nice approach)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't fill the pie slices with images.